# why window.loadFirebugConsole() is being called on pageload?

Tags: javascript, iframe, dojo

An iframe is being created with the below line, whenever i am including dojo/enhancedgrid in my page:

```
<iframe src="javascript:'
  <html>
    <head>
      <script>

        if("loadFirebugConsole" in window){
          window.loadFirebugConsole();
        }
        </script>
      </head>
    <body>
  </body>
  </html>'
">
```

Can anyone tell why it is created and how can i removed it?
Thanks in advance for any suggestion

Comment: What is your Dojo version ? You can just remove it from your HTML code, or you can just remove the if statement. Check why your variable `loadFirebugConsole` is set to true in your window.

Comment: Dojo version is 1.9.1

Comment: Could you provide the creation code of the grid ? I don't see anything related to your problem in the Dojo doc.

Comment: I think that is included when u have the dojo debug flag on

Comment: I am including the below line in all my JSP's except my home page but still the iframe is there in the home page also.

     dojoConfig = {parseOnLoad: true, isDebug: true,async:true};

Do i have to remove isDebug: true from all the pages?