# dojo adding iframe with loadFirebugConsole - how to disable?

Tags: javascript, dojo, arcgis, esri

I am suing dojo for some development , and at some point it just decides to add that :

```
 <iframe src="javascript:'<html><head><script>if(&quot;loadFirebugConsole&quot; in window){window.loadFirebugConsole();}</script></head><body></body></html>'" style="position: absolute; width: 5em; height: 10em; top: -10000px; display: none;"></iframe>
```

Now I know it is related to dojo trying to load firebug lite , and that the isDebug on the dojoConfig SHOULD control it.

But it just doesnt work

[I did read that one , but it has no answer and the comments doesnt help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23904853/why-window-loadfirebugconsole-is-being-called-on-pageload)

I did try to avoid it with ,useCustomLogger,debugContainerId and all the options with isDebug.
still it just appears.

Any ideas ?

Comment: BTW, just noticed you did not mentioned what kind of issue the iframe is raising ? Does it creates a JS error, a cosmetic issue ?

Comment: if I would look at it inside a browser it wouldnt show any problem at all. the thing is that I use that inside an iframe in a document management system , and there I need to permit any external source as trusted-source ( it is m-files) the thing is because the iframe src="javascript:...." there is no visible way to permit it inside the DMS config file

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be added by some dojox components:
`dojox/html/ellipsis` If Using Firefox lower than version 7)
and `dojox/html/metrics` (when init is done).

I bet you use `dojox/html/metrics`.
I bet this should be changed in dojo itself as it is a workaround for a very old firefox/firebug version

Dojo code says:

> //The script tag is to work around a known firebug race condition.  See comments in bug #9046

I guess you can open the file `dojox/html/metrics` and kill the line creating the frame (search for `loadFirebugConsole`)

I proposed Dojo Team to remove this workaround (as it is 6 years old)...
See https://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/9046#comment:19

Comment: Thanks @ben for writing that , this is the part I know. The thing is that it is a part of the Arcgis framework that is loaded remotely from a CDN, particularly  in esri/dijit/edit/editor , that means I cannot just remove the line(especially from the minified version).

Comment: Look like if `dojoConfig.fontSizeWatch = false`, metrics will not add the iframe (because it will not run its `initOnFontResize` method)
Otherwise, as a workaround you could remove the iframe when dom is ready (dojo adds it when dom is ready)

Comment: the fontSizeWatch , didnt work. and the iframe is added only when I activate a specific dijit and not on dom load, of course I could remove it , the thing is that it is running inside a shell that - because of the addition itself popups an alert - this is why I try to avoid it

Comment: Do you know which dojo version is used ?

Comment: it is using dojo 1.10.4